# How can I install a downloaded Firefox add-on?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser-addons

I have [downloaded the BetterPrivacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6623) Firefox add-on to disk (file name "betterprivacy-1.29-fx.xpi", 24 KB) outside of Firefox (Windows).

How do I install this add-on into Firefox?

(I know that the downloading and installing can be done from within Firefox, but assume for now that this possibility does not exist.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the *File* → *Open File...* menu item to open the .xpi file and Firefox will install the add-on.

Answer (score 6):

Just drag & drop the file into Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can simply drag the .xpi file into the Add-ons window.

Answer (score 2):

Or right click on the XPI file → *Open with* → *Firefox*.

There are plenty ways to skin that cat :)