# How do I install an add-on from a file in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions, browser-addons

I am running Mozilla Firefox 76.0.1.

I would like to install an add-on from a .xpi file.

This question was asked 10 years ago [here](https://superuser.com/questions/29540/firefox-how-to-install-a-downloaded-add-on), but the answer has changed.

Now, whether I open the add-on from the "File" menu as suggested above, or whether I follow the instructions from [support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-and-install-add-ons-add-features-to-firefox),

> For advanced users: You can also install add-ons from a file. If you saved the installer file to your computer, (for example, an .xpi or .jar file) you can install the add-on using the gear icon gear icon in the upper-right area of the Add-on Manager Extensions panel. Select Install Add-on from file... from the menu, then find and select the file.

either way I run into trouble:

[image: image of firefox blocking add-on install]

I am not trying to hack into my own computer; all I'm trying to do is change an extension I use to be less annoying. Is there a way I can do this without recompiling Firefox as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can do this without recompiling Firefox as well?

Firefox removed the ability to use unsigned add-ons, with the release of Firefox 44 which was 32 versions ago, which is about 4 years ago.  The developer version of Firefox should allow you to use unsigned add-ons.

You also have to allow unsigned add-ons by setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` to **false**.  As for the instructions you linked to, it's written under the assumption, you are attempting to install a signed add-on.

> [Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR)](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/), [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/developer/) and [Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) versions of Firefox will allow you to override the setting to enforce the extension signing requirement, by changing the preference `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in the Firefox Configuration Editor (about:config page). To override the language pack signing requirement, you would set the preference `extensions.langpacks.signatures.required` to `false`. There are also special unbranded versions of Firefox that allow this override. See the MozillaWiki article, Add-ons/Extension Signing for more information.

Source:

- [What are my options if I want to use an unsigned add-on? (advanced users)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox)
- [Firefox Browser Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)